# Java - (My 4th test case taking too long to give output)

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime

I am having some trouble with my java program. The job of my program is, if the word count is more than 10, then it would paste the first word, number of words between them + and the last word

And if the word count is less than 10, then it is just going to paste the word.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String pkt[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int loopnumber= sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); 

        while (loopnumber>0){

            String word = sc.nextLine();

            int length = word.length(); //to count String length
            int n= length-2; // wordcount between them

            if(length>10){ //will print first and last later of the string and the number-count between them
                System.out.println(word.charAt(0)+ "" + n + "" +word.charAt(length-1));
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(word);
            }
            loopnumber--;
        }
    }
}
```

When I input

```
4
word
localization
internationalization
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

the first three case just runs fine. As for the last one, which is `pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis`, my program is taking too long to respond for this one. About more than 30 seconds...

But when I just input

```
1
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

then my program runs just fine. It gives an instant output. Although both the test cases (`pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis`) are the same.

Comment: I cannot reproduce any delay when running your code with the input provided. If the timeout is from some automated judging program, it is possible that you diverged from the expected output format somewhere. How are you running the program?

Comment: If you make sure there is a line break after the last word, it behaves as expected. I suspect you copy it and paste it without one.

Comment: @Sam Thank you Sam... It worked this time. But would you mind explaining why it happened?

Comment: @teapot418 thank you for taking the time to reply. I just copy-pasted code forces input this time and it worked. But I dont know why it failed at first

Comment: At the end of a line there is a line feed character (and a carriage return character if Windows). When you select some text you might or might not include that character. When you copy more than one line, you can't miss it, except for the last line. In this case you missed the one on the last line. This missed character is the signal for the scanner class to process the line.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The job of my program is, if the word count is more than 10, then it would paste the first word, number of words between them + and the last word ..."*

As reference, these are typically called *characters*, or *chars*.

Here is an example.
Note, you can skip the *nextLine* advance, and just use the *[next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next())* method.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String s;
int n = in.nextInt(), sn;
while (n-- > 0)
    if ((sn = (s = in.next()).length()) > 10)
        System.out.printf("%s%s%s%n", s.charAt(0), sn - 2, s.charAt(sn - 1));
    else System.out.println(s);
```

Output

```
4
word
word
localization
l10n
internationalization
i18n
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
p43s
```